# How to make a grid have the same vertical space in its rows with children divs with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How to make a grid have the same vertical space in its rows with children divs with Tailwind

code of the problem:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<main class="flex h-fit h-screen">
  <div class="text-primaryTextColor bg-primaryMainBg ml-2 mr-4 h-full w-full rounded-2xl p-3">
    <ul class="grid grid-cols-7 gap-3 pb-1">
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">LUN</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">MAR</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">MIÉ</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">JUE</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">VIE</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">SÁB</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">DOM</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="grid h-full grid-cols-7 gap-3 pb-6">
      <a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li>
          <div class="mb-2">29</div>
          <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
            <div class="flex grow">G1</div>
            <div class="flex">1000</div>
          </div>
          <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
            <div class="flex grow">G 2</div>
            <div class="flex">2000</div>
          </div>
          <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
            <div class="flex grow">G 3</div>
            <div class="flex">3000</div>
          </div>
          <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
            <div class="flex grow">G 4</div>
            <div class="flex">4000</div>
          </div>
        </li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">30</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">31</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">1</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">2</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">3</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">4</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">5</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">6</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">7</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">8</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">9</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">10</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">11</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">12</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">13</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">14</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">15</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">16</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">17</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">18</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">19</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">20</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">21</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">22</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">23</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">24</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">25</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">26</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">27</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">28</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">29</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">30</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">1</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">2</div></li></a
      >
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

I want divs (G1...G4) of the first cell of the grid don't take up vertical space on the parent div and all the cells of the grid to take the same vertical space with a responsive design.

The final result grid that I want is the same as if it doesn't have the children divs G1...G4, all cells have the same height

How can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the elements in another element that has `position: absolute` via the `absolute` class to take them out of the usual layout flow:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<main class="flex h-fit h-screen">
  <div class="text-primaryTextColor bg-primaryMainBg ml-2 mr-4 h-full w-full rounded-2xl p-3">
    <ul class="grid grid-cols-7 gap-3 pb-1">
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">LUN</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">MAR</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">MIÉ</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">JUE</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">VIE</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">SÁB</li>
      <li class="select-none list-none text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500">DOM</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="grid h-full grid-cols-7 gap-3 pb-6">
      <a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li>
          <div class="mb-2">29</div>
          <div class="absolute">
            <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
              <div class="flex grow">G1</div>
              <div class="flex">1000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
              <div class="flex grow">G 2</div>
              <div class="flex">2000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
              <div class="flex grow">G 3</div>
              <div class="flex">3000</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shrink-1 m-0.5 flex bg-red-300 pl-2 pr-2">
              <div class="flex grow">G 4</div>
              <div class="flex">4000</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">30</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">31</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">1</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">2</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">3</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">4</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">5</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">6</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">7</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">8</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">9</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">10</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">11</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">12</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">13</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">14</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">15</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">16</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">17</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">18</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">19</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">20</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">21</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">22</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">23</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">24</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">25</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">26</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">27</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">28</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">29</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">30</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">1</div></li></a
      ><a class="active:bg-primaryOptionSelected cursor-pointer select-none list-none border bg-gray-50 bg-opacity-50 pt-1 text-center text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 duration-300 hover:shadow-md hover:shadow-gray-300" href="/crearGasto"
        ><li><div class="mb-2">2</div></li></a
      >
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Now I have another problem that I will ask in another question